# Reported speech commands - negations which aren't related to subject

Tags: negation, indirect-speech, imperatives

First my english ain't pretty good but I hope you can understand me. :)
So at the moment I'm doing my homework and I'm pre-finished with it but 2 sentences are very difficult for the exercise.

I need to put commands in direct speech to the reported speech.

**For example:**

Mother: *Don't lose your passport. Keep it somewhere safe*.
-> My mother told me not to lose my passport. She told me to keep it somewhere safe.

That's pretty simple but this sentence the negation are not related to the subject or I don't know how I can can describe this ... :/

Mother: *Take a present for your French family. It doesn't have to be something expensive.*
-> My mother told me to take a present for my French family.
But she told me it not have to be something expensive.

I think that's wrong because it sounds wrong .. :/

Do I need it in this way: ....
 But she told me that it doesn't have to be expensive or something like this?
Kinda weird grammar :/

And this sentence is also difficult:

Mother: *The journey won't feel so long.*

Does anyone has any solutions?:)

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But she told me [that] it **did** not have to be something expensive.

In your example, the person who receives the command (*me*) is not the same as the primary argument (*it*) of the verb that describes the action to be taken (*have to be...*), as you say. For that reason, you cannot use [*told* + person spoken to + *to* + infinitive], but you rather need to use a full subordinate clause starting with *that* (which word can be omitted) and an actual subject + finite verb, in this case *it* + *did*.

> She told me [that] the journey *would't* feel so long.

Generally, the finite verb in the subordinate clauses will be in the past tense if the main clause is also in the past tense, although the present tense (*won't*) is probably also acceptable.